# sed, append line on match only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: sed

#### Using sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2, I want to:

1. Match `Line1`
2. Check `Line2`, just below `Line1`, if it equals `String`
3. If it doesn't - append `String` after `Line1` (or insert before `Line2`)

#### What I tried:

```
echo -e "Line1\nLine2\nLine3" | sed '/Line1/n;/^String$/!iString'
```

but it returns:

> Line1
> String
> Line2
> String
> Line3

#### I also tried:

```
echo -e "Line1\nLine2\nLine3" | sed '/Line1/{n;/^String$/!iString}'
```

but it returns

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

I know how to do it another way, also using sed, but I try to understand how to achieve it the exact way as I described it above. Also, please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Commands `i` , `a` and `c` consider all text after as it's own text. You have to break the command with literal new line or split the sed line in two or more commands with `-e` option `echo -e "Line1\nLine2\nLine3" | sed -e '/Line1/ {n;/^String$/!iString' -e '}'`

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand why '{' was unmatched.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
sed '/Line1/{N; /\nString$/b; s/\n/\nString\n/}' file
```

*Limitation:*  If two lines with `Line1` appear in a row, this may or may not do what you want.

#### Example

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
Line1
String
Line2
String
Line3
Line1
Line2
```

And, let's apply our command:

```
$ sed '/Line1/{N; /\nString$/b; s/\n/\nString\n/}' file
Line1
String
Line2
String
Line3
Line1
String
Line2
```

#### How it works

- `Line1/{...}`

  This executes the commands in curly braces only if the current line matches the regex `Line1`.
- `N`

  This reads in the next line and appends it to the current line with the two lines separated by a newline.
- `/\nString$/b`

  If the second line matches the regex `\nString$`, then skip over the remainder of the commands ("branch", `b`).
- `s/\n/\nString\n/`

  This replaces the newline that separates the first and second lines with newline followed by `String` followed by another newline.

Comment: It's a bit other approach, but it does the job, thank you.